# White Text on White Background When Saving Files in Brave

Tags: brave

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, got most things to work well, and am now mostly working on a few minor issues :)

When I want to save a file in the Brave Browser, the file name is white on white background:

See Image

[image: See image].

This doesn't happen in, say, Chromium, only Brave. I haven't tweaked the appearance in any way, and it looks fine if I change Gnome to the dark theme.

I guess my question is why that happens, and if there is a way to change the text color to black?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it?

Answer (score 0):

try
brave://settings/appearance

you might get lucky with toggling between Light and Dark themes.

at worst, you might have to scroll all the way to the bottom and choose

```
    Reset settings
    Restore settings to their original defaults
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing Brave theme didn't work, but I ended up changing to the dark Ubuntu theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. my ubuntu version is 20.04LTS, I changed to dark theme, light theme, GTK+ or classic nothing works!
unfortunately I don't have  enough reputation to comment this.